# meaning of "here we go"

Tags: meaning-in-context, idioms

> "Hagrid," said Harry, panting a bit as he ran to keep up, "did you say there are dragons at Gringotts?"
>      "Well, so they say," said Hagrid. "Crikey, I'd like a dragon."
>      "You'd like one?"
>      "Wanted one ever since I was a kid –– ***here we go***."
>      They had reached the station. There was a train to London in five minutes' time. Hagrid, who didn't understand "Muggle money," as he called it, gave the bills to Harry so he could buy their tickets.
>      <sub>*(Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)*</sub>

Does the phrase mean ‘*let’s go*’ or ‘[said when something bad starts happening again’](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/here-we-go-again)?
(I guess the latter is more likely that Hagrid seems to blame himself.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you give someone something you can say "Here you go" to the person you are giving it to.

If I was bringing someone to the train station for example, I might say "here you go" on arriving at the station. I have given them the train station.

If I was bringing someone to the train station and I was also going to be travelling with them on the train, I might then say "here we go" on arriving at the station. I have given us  the train station. This is the meaning of the sentence you mention above.

I would say "Here we go again" if someone started doing something again and again and that something was annoying me.

Answer (score 3):

The following sentence, *They had reached the station* reveals the meaning of *here we go*. Hagrid was drawing attention to the fact that they had arrived at the destination, being the station.

Answer (score 3):

"Here we go" could have different meanings, depending on situation, or how you say it. If you start telling a story that we all heard a dozen time, I'd say "Here we go..." indicating by voice how boring it is. If I help an old lady who isn't very firm on her feet to walk to another place, I might say "here we go" as a friendly, slightly condescending form of "start walking". When the first rocket of a fireworks goes up in the air, "Here we go" means "now the action starts". If I know the right way and walk ahead of a group and enter the correct one of three possible paths, I say "here we go" as "follow me".

In this case, Baz's third paragraph is exactly right. But consider if the text had continued: "'Wanted one ever since I was a kid –– here we go'. They had reached the station, and five armed policemen appeared out of nowhere". Suddenly it's "said when something bad starts happening".

Answer (score 3):

The Oxford Advanced Learner's dictionary has an entry for *"here we go"* that applies perfectly to the quoted text:

> **here we go** (spoken) said when something is starting to happen: *"Here we go," thought Fred, "she's sure to say something."*

In the context of the quoted text, Hagrid says *"here we go"* because they are about to reach the station.